# Styling differences in SwiftUI Button in list context: iOS 15 vs. earlier

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15

With this example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["Hello, world!"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
            }, label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            })
            .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

on iOS 14, this looks like:

[image]

on iOS 15, it now looks like:

[image]

It is rather surprising the number of styling differences:

1. The corner rounding: In iOS 15, but not earlier
2. The text color: In iOS 15, blue and white earlier.
3. The width of the view-- considerably narrower in iOS 15

Is this just an expected change with iOS 15?

Is there a standard way to not have these changes occur? I.e., to retain the earlier styling?

Comment: Apple changes UI style regularly in each new OS version, so as soon as you use default styles your app will look natively on OS. If you want to have unique persistent style, then develop and use everywhere your completely custom UI based on low level UI primitives.

Comment: What `low level UI primitives`? SwiftUI? UIKit? I've not experienced such major changes in UIKit. Do you know of documentation stating these changes?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at this interesting summary for further information about the iOS15 button system ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2021/2110064/ 

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple has changed its default UI elements states. This can also be seen in Safari where webpages have no CSS for forms.

Comment: Do you know of documentation on these states?

Comment: I haven't seen any "change documeation" from apple but to change the UI, you just need to change it from its default state

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer that helped me was the use of `.listStyle`. In my original code, I didn't use `.listStyle`, and apparently the default has changed. So, if I do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["Hello, world!"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
            }, label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            })
            .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

I get a result closer to what I want.

Apparently the `.listStyle` default is now [`insetGrouped`](https://robsturgeon.medium.com/new-features-in-swiftui-on-ios-15-246b0159494d), which is not what I wanted.